# Why is Cloud Endpoints throwing com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException while mapping POJOs in a List?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm receiving this error:

```
com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token↵ at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.test.web.TestFM["fields"])
```

I've mocked up a simplified version of my situation that throws the same error:

Cloud Endpoint:

```
@Api(name = "testApi", version = "v1", clientIds={Constants.WEB_CLIENT_ID, com.google.api.server.spi.Constant.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID})
public class TestEndpoint {
    public void Test(TestFM test){
        // nothing necessary here to recreate
    }
}
```

TestFM:

```
public class TestFM {
    public int id;
    public List<SubTestFM> fields;
}
```

SubTestFM:

```
public class SubTestFM {
    public String property1;
    public String property2;
}
```

Javascript:

```
gapi.client.testApi.testEndpoint.test({
    id:7, 
    fields:[
        { property1: 'test', property2: 'test2' }, 
        { property1: 'test3', property2: 'test4' }
    ]
}).execute(function(resp){console.log(resp);});
```

I had thought this might be a limitation of endpoints until I realized that **when submitting the same data through the API Explorer, everything works exactly as expected.**

The successful Request produced by API Explorer:

```
POST http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/testApi/v1/Test

Content-Type:  application/json
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
 "id": 7,
 "fields": [
  {
   "property1": "test",
   "property2": "test2"
  },
  {
   "property1": "test3",
   "property2": "test4"
  }
 ]
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading my question, I realized there was a reasonable probability that the field name "fields" is reserved or otherwise used by one of the libraries involved in Google Cloud Endpoints.

Changing the name from "fields" (in TestFM above) has resolved this error in the test code above and in my own code.

Comment: That's probably it.  See: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Disallowed_Property_Names for example of names you're not supposed to use.

Comment: @dyoo Thanks for the research. I couldn't find any similar disclaimer on the Java side, and the model actually appears to persist to the datastore without issue (disclaimer: I have not run the app in production). It would be nice if Google included a similar note for cloud endpoints.

Comment: Agreed.  I sent documentation feedback; hopefully this doc bug can be corrected shortly.